# MySQL "load data local infile" just loads 1 row

Tags: mysql, import, load-data-infile

I need to upload a csv file to my MySQL table. For some reason, when I run the command below in Mac Terminal, just one row is inserted. How can I upload all the rows?

```
load data local infile 'Research/cube_sample_data.csv' 
into table ad_spend 
fields terminated by ',' 
lines terminated by '\n';
```

I tried `'\r\n'` and `',\r\n'` but no success. I keep getting this message:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected, 0 warnings (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

my file is like this:

```
entertainment, games, 14

entertainment, movies, 12
```

and I have an empty table with 3 columns:

```
category (varchar), subcat (varchar), adspend (int)
```

Comment: You're going to have to post some sample lines from that file and a schema for that table, otherwise we can't really help.

Comment: my file is like this: entertainment, games, 14 and I have an empty table with 3 columns: category (varchar), subcat (varchar), adspend (int)

Comment: Your file has empty lines. Remove these empty lines. Also check which end-of-line character the file is using.

Comment: It doesn't have empty lines, it looks like it here. It's a csv file created by Excel. Any way to check it though? I see it in TextEdit and it looks fine.

Comment: hakre, you were right. I need to save it as Windows Comma Separated. Saving it as usual Mac csv, adds an invisible line between lines. It's not even visible in TextEdit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there's not only a comma between fields, but also a whitespace. So try to use:

```
fields terminated by ', '
```

Comment: I need to save it as Windows Comma Separated. Saving it as usual Mac csv, adds an invisible line between lines. It's not even visible in TextEdit.